bootstrap modal, close only if input value matches
i am new with coding, very beginner level. i want simple bootstrap 5 modal, where only have two options.
input
close button
and i want close button to work only if input has value 123.
thank you
example i am using
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>

